# Is pork for bo ssam made entirely without oil?

Tags: oil, oven, pork

According to all the recipes, we have to leave the salted and covered with sugar pork in the fridge over night. In the morning we wash it, wipe it dry and put it in the oven - so no oil. I'm not used to cook without the oil, so I'm interested in if that's ok?

Recipe: http://mobile.nytimes.com/2012/01/15/magazine/recipe-momofuku-bo-ssam.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YUM! I lived in Seoul for a year, Bo Ssam is one of the best things I've ever tasted. You're using pork shoulder (butt) right? If so, no oil is necessary. There is plenty of fat in the pork.

Comment: Yes, I'm using pork shoulder. Thanks, can't wait it comes out of the oven!

Comment: @genesiss I wish I was there! :)

Comment: ah just made bossam last night.  enjoy!